# how to use request variable in model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have an app with different countries based on the domain of the request.

I have a country model and based on the request it loads the locale.

Now I have an issue with the user model. The countries have different user login, i.e. one country has the CAS for the SSO and another one has the normal registration.

I am using Devise and I would like to check the country first and then add an IF in the user model to check the country and load the devise configuration for that country.

Something like

```
if country == "uk"
devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :trackable, :validatable, :timeoutable,
     :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook, :google_oauth2]
else
devise :invitable, :cas_authenticatable, :registerable,
      :recoverable, :trackable, :validatable, :timeoutable
end
```

How can I check the country and then apply an if statement in the model?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The thing to keep in mind is that declarations like `devise` happen when the model is loaded, something that's normally done once and once only in production mode, so you can't add any behaviour that's conditional based on what might happen in the future when `country` is actually defined.

What you can do is subclass your model using "Single Table Inheritance" (STI) to have two different kinds of users:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class GenericUser < User
  devise :invitable, ...
end

class UkUser < User
  devise :invitable, ..., omniauth_providers: [ ... ]
end
```

This involves adding a string `type` column to your schema, but is otherwise minimally impacting. In your controller you'll have to create the appropriate user type as well:

```
@user =
  case (country)
  when 'uk'
    UkUser.create(params[:user])
  else
    GenericUser.create(params[:user])
  end
```

Or some variation of that pattern. You can also create a factory method:

```
class User
  def self.create_for_country(params)
    model_type =
      case (params[:user][:country])
      when 'uk'
        UkUser
      else
        GenericUser
      end

    model_type.create(params[:user])
 end
```

Comment: Good answer but that factory method should be something like `def self.create_for_country(attributes)` and should take whitelisted attributes from the controller as models cannot access `request` and whitelisting is a controller concern.